# Querying Cloud Kit Core Data Record

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I have a app that I'm trying to migrate over to using CloudKit to store the core data so it can be synced across devices.

The syncing is working fine, the issue I'm having is that the app adds some initial data to the database, this is causing it to be duplicated when its installed on another device. Currently I'm using user defaults to store a bool locally if the first run has been performed, which obviously only works per device

Is there any way to see if data already exists in the cloud and prevent the addition of the initial data.

Apple's documentation would suggest its possible if an object already exists but on first launch there's no objects in the local store.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/reading_cloudkit_records_for_core_data

Comment: If I'm following the question....I'd generally do a CloudKit query to check to see if the data exists, if so, set local store, but don't save the data to CloudKit, so you avoid the duplicate.  If it doesn't exist, then you are safe to go ahead.

Comment: How do I do the query? There’s plenty of non core data examples but can’t find any for core data

Comment: Maybe I'm mixed up now :). But I thought the issue was with the CloudKit query to see if data is in CloudKit - or are you saying the issue is CoreData?  If you can maybe give slightly more color, I'm happy to give an example.

Comment: Currently, device 1 has a new install which setups the initial data the app uses. This gets synced into CloudKit. Device 2 then is setup, this does an initial setup of data, the same as device 1, but it also syncs the initial data that device 1 has already synced. I was thinking to query CloudKit and see if there's any data there before doing the initial setup

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both devices are using the same CloudKit login then, if the data you want to check is stored on the User record you could do this:

1. Grab the CloudKit ID for that user

```
func iCloudUserIDAsync(complete: @escaping (_ instance: CKRecord.ID?, _ error: NSError?) -> ()) {
        let container = CKContainer.default()
        container.fetchUserRecordID() {
            recordID, error in
            
            if let error = error {
               //handle
            } else {
                self.userRecordID = recordID
                complete(recordID, nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Then use that ID to query CloudKit at get the user back:

```swift
CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: userRecordID) { (results, error ) in
     if results != nil {
         //got the user record, do what you want with it
     }
     if let error = error {
         //handle error
     }
}
```

Alternatively, if your data isn't on the user record, then you'll want to do a query using CKQueryOperation and predicates:  Good tutorial here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4878052-cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Do you know of any way to do this with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer or must you do a direct CloudKit records search for the initial app launch?

Comment: Afraid I haven't dealt enough with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer so can't comment on that one.  Sorry!

Comment: No problem! I do believe that’s what the OP @ceriturner was attempting to use